# What can I do if I want to answer a protected question without having the required reputation to do so?

Tags: support, reputation, protected-questions

… although I have more than enough on Stack Overflow.

The question I'm trying to answer is: [Rails - Does using partials slow views rendering?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157108/rails-does-using-partials-slow-views-rendering)

This problem has annoyed me for awhile.

I found the solution by chance - naturally - but only after I started to analyze everything in depth.

I am pretty sure that my answer could help many developers.

So - how do I get the missing 4 reputation points?

I could ask and self-answer the same question, but it would be closed as a duplicate and/or possibly deleted.

Edit - So not - I know the solution for that question.
I tried to help
On the other hand - rules are rules.

Edit II: I never asked about a bonus - I don't even care.

Comment: Suggest 2 good edits (maybe a tag wiki and excerpt)

Comment: Wait, the question you link isn't locked, and unless it is you don't need any rep to answer? Can you elaborate what's shown if you try to post an answer please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it is protected, they need 10 rep on the site. Association bonus doesn't count here.

Comment: @rene Oh, I didn't spot that. Is the protection only shown to users who can't post an answer?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I didn't either, I had to open the timeline with the votes view to find it :(

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - ναι.- Yes - "Highly active question. Earn 10 reputation in order to answer …"

Comment: @halfbit Well, just as mentioned, it's not that hard to get 10 points rep. Just make five good edits and you'll overcome that hurdle.

Comment: Or assume my name and get a free pass :D

Comment: _“So how do I get the missing 4 reputation points?”_ — Why 4? You need 10.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The protection notice is only shown to users who don't have enough rep to answer or who have enough rep to protect questions. Others can only see that a question is protected in the post history.

Comment: @sonic Ty for giving the insight.I was already wonering why I see that message at some question at SO.

Comment: @user289905 - I have 6 (at the moment) I need 10 -> 4 missing. Or what do I miss?

Comment: @halfbit Your [account on Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/144167/halfbit) currently has 101 reputation points. This is from the association bonus. As it doesn’t count, you need 10 more reputation points, or 111 in total. You don’t have 6 reputation points anywhere. Are you confusing badges with reputation?

Comment: @user289905 true - the "6" before is gone (prob. timings), now 101, 
how ever, "Highly active question. Earn 10 reputation in order to answer this question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam and non-answer activity. " 
Is the text I can read.
And how ever - I do not care to share my answer anymore.
Stack has rules, I accept them.

Comment: This is a valid support question, and I'm sorry that the rules of Stack Exchange prevented you from posting a  possibly good answer, @halfbit. It's a loss for everyone, both to you personally as you wasted time and efforts, and for other people who won't see the answer and might need it. If you can do as the answer suggests and earn 10 points on that site it would be great for everyone, you will be able to post the answer, and hopefully get upvotes and badges for it. There are also badges for answers posted on old question, when the answers get enough upvotes. Cheers, and good luck! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask: thx for your motivating words. Indeed it is frustrating, when you can help and are not allowed to. 
And yes - rules are rules - I more than accept this.

Comment: @halfbit good luck.  Remember, it'll only take one upvote/2 edits!

Comment: If you have at least 5 reputation (including the association bonus, if you have it), you can request on the site's meta to have protection removed. Sometimes questions get protected due to an issue that passed a long time ago.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog, so I just asked the wrong way?
Not: "What to do" just: "please remove?"

Comment: You'd have to ask a question on the site's own *per-site* meta, not here. You can access that meta by going to the site, then using the drop-down in the top right. This site only deals with general matters affecting the whole of the network of sites.

Answer (score 7):

> What can I do if I want to answer a protected question without having the required reputation to do so?

You can't answer the question directly unless you have earned ten reputation on that specific site.  To get the required reputation, you can suggest good edits which, when accepted, are worth 2 reputation, or post a well-accepted question or answer.  It'll only take one upvote.

**Note:**  The +100 reputation association bonus is ignored in cases like this.  You would need 110 in total.